# How to pass custom list with putextra

Tags: java, list, kotlin, android-intent, pass-data

I'm trying to pass List data throught my service with putextra. I didn't do it. How can i do that.

```
fun startService(context: Context, path: String,action: String,list:List<Musics>) {
        val startIntent = Intent(context, ForegroundService::class.java)
        startIntent.putExtra("path", path)
        startIntent.putExtra("action",action)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent)
    }
```

**Above code is my startService code**

```
@Entity(tableName = "musics")
data class Musics(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid:Int= 0,
@ColumnInfo(name = "file_name") val filename:String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "file_path") val filepath:String
)
```

**My data class**

And I want to pass my List(Musics) data.

Comment: Have you got a solution ? @Tunahan

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Actually "mightyWOZ" 's answer worked. However I used database like he said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to pass large data sets between different components is to store the data in local database and pass some key in the `Intent` and then retrieve the data using the key.
But if you still need to do that your way, follow below listed steps

**Make Musics class implement serializable interface**

```
data class Musics : Serializable
```

**When starting Service you can do**

```
val yourList: ArrayList<Musics>
startIntent.putExtra("myList", yourList)
```

**In your service get your list from Intent as following**

```
val list: List<Musics> = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myList") as List<Musics>
```

Comment: startIntent.putExtra("myList", yourList) this method is giving error.  (None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.) It doesn't work

Comment: youList must of type ArrayList